# How to solve this leak _NSCFstring UIKIT

Tags: xcode, memory, memory-leaks

Hello I am a newbie to xcode, I have got memory leaks in my app like this below

```
Object :_NSCFString
Bytes: 48Bytes
Library: UIkit
Frame: [UIStatusBarTimeItemView UpdateForNewData
```

and i can't figure out the reason ,I have used (uiwebview which loads different jquery mobile pages) in my project Please help...

Answer (score 0):

You can run the Leaks instrument in Instruments.app (hit "Profile" rather than "Run" in Xcode). It will record the sources of allocations, including backtraces, and even reference count operations (as an option which is off by default).

Exercise the area of the program you are interested while recording.

Then you examine the leaks it finds, and remove all of them, unless impossible and a bug with another library you use.

Comment: Yes i did as you said but the leak is pointing to Main.m file as "@autoreleasepool {
      return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }"

Comment: @user1592279 you probably have drill down or invert the call tree in instruments to see the full backtrace. that, or focusing on a single leak in the other presentation/table.

Comment: Ok im still in  confusion, look at this screenshot http://imgur.com/WvVoU when i highlight the leak it shows only "main" in detail view

Comment: @user1592279 you've read the stack trace in the opposite order. read it like this: The leaked allocation was created by `CFAllocatorAllocate`, which was called by `_CFRuntimeCreateInstance`, which was called by…

Comment: As I already said that I'm a beginner so sorry for the repeated question, but when i click CFAllocatorAllocate i doesn't takes me to the line of code where it leaks instead its showing this http://i.imgur.com/2ZfPD.png am i wrong again?

Comment: @Sandy88 yup. CFAllocatorAllocate is defined in CoreFoundation. running in debug is one of the first steps -- it's easier to read, and for instruments to symbolicate. anyways, you typically walk up the callstack to the nearest responsible call from your app or library. just focus on what your program does with that allocation, not the implementation of CFAllocatorAllocate. (cont)

Comment: (cont) having seen your leak - i'd focus on other individual leaks in that set because that one which you have selected looks kind of deep in UIKit (maybe the UIStatusBar is being used improperly?). you won't need to look at the assembly of other libraries to figure these out. just focus on your programs' implementations. usually, that's where the issue is (although Apple's programs leak too). if you have a bunch of leaks, sometimes they are related to each other or the library may have been misused, or a threading error -- it's not always a ref count imbalance on your side.

Comment: I have implemented a sliding menu like Facebook app by following an online tutorial so I think this must be the culprit which causes leak because the animation contains  two views

Comment: perhaps. i also noticed there was a leaked NSAutoreleasePool - those and collections (e.g. leaked NSArray, NSDictionary) types are the first i target. in some cases, you may want to set a breakpoint for all thrown exceptions. in the event an exception is thrown, it will obviously not send release as it unwinds (it would if C++ smart pointers were used, but that's not typical). also, Instruments can be configured to record every ref count operation. i figure there are videos (e.g. from WWDC) which detail this debug process better than i can in comment boxes.